# Generate all possible couples with given two tuples

Tags: python

I need to build a function in python that inputs two tuples and returns all the possible pairs for example.

`def mult_tuple(tuple1,tuple2):`

let the tuples be:

`first_tuple = (1,2) 
 second_tuple = (4,5)`

and the output will be:

`((1,4),(4,1),(1,5),(5,1),(2,4),(4,2),(2,5),(5,2))`

**Note**: The input tuples can be of any size. For eg: `(1,4) and (8,2,9,6)`

Comment: Does the order of the output matter?

Comment: My last meal was fine, thank you. Can you please show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `product` from `itertools`

```
import itertools

for element in itertools.product((1,2),(3,4,5,6)):
    print(element, (element[1],element[0]))
```

and output will be:

```
(1, 3) (3, 1)
(1, 4) (4, 1)
(1, 5) (5, 1)
(1, 6) (6, 1)
(2, 3) (3, 2)
(2, 4) (4, 2)
(2, 5) (5, 2)
(2, 6) (6, 2)
```

so your func will be for example

```
def mult_tuple(tuple1,tuple2):
  for element in itertools.product(tuple1, tuple2):
    yield element
    yield (element[1],element[0])
```

you can get more info here
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product